# Problem with fluent-ffmpeg in node.js with firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, ffmpeg

I am using fluent-ffmpeg to compress video to 1000k bit rate for the videos that is uploaded by the user to firebase.

```
  console.log("Compressed File Path: " + compressedVideoFilePath);
  const command = ffmpeg(tempFilePath).setFfmpegPath(ffmpegStatic.path)
                                              .videoBitrate(1000)
                                              //.audioChannels(1)
                                              //.audioFrequency(16000)
                                              //.format('flac')
                                              .on('error', function(err) {
                                                console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
                                              })
                                              .on('end', function() {
                                                console.log('Processing finished!');
                                                console.log("File compressed");
                                                return destBucket.upload(compressedVideoFilePath, {
                                                  destination: 'compressed-' + path.basename(filePath),
                                                  metadata: metadata
                                                }).then(() => {
                                                  console.log('Output audio uploaded to', targetStorageFilePath);

                                                  // Once the audio has been uploaded delete the local file to free up disk space.
                                                  fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
                                                  fs.unlinkSync(targetTempFilePath);

                                                  console.log('Temporary files removed.', targetTempFilePath);
                                                });
                                              })
                                              .save(compressedVideoFilePath);
  console.log("Function Finished");
```

But, the code inside ffmpeg does not run, the output of the console is just:

```
Compressed File Path: /tmp/compressed-test-4d68b02f-a6ef-4ff3-a5c9-52687fd3f0c4.mp4 
Function Finished
Function execution took 17871 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

It just skips to the end without displaying any on end or on success messages. The compressed video files also did not appear/uploaded in the firebase.

Can anyone help me find out the problem and help me fix it? Is the code for ffmpeg not correct? Thanks.

Comment: you defined ffmpeg as a function but ... you did not call the function as defined

Comment: Um... Does that mean I have to add command(); before console.log("Function Finished");? Thanks

Comment: I don't think its this problem, it shows: TypeError: command is not a function.